# sql in python functions

Tags: python, sql

I have tables as the following:

```
table1: name born country id
        A    1943  UK      3
        B    1966  USA     2...
table2: artist_id  artist_name formation
        3           The Beatles  1960
        2           The Door     USA
```

so i am struggling how to write the following function, can somebody give me an idea to start?

```
def band_by_country(sql_cursor,country):
'''(sqlite3.Cursor,str)->list of[]
return a list of bands representing all the bands who have at least one member who was born in that country.
>>>band_by_country(sql_cursor, UK)
['The Beatles']
>>>band_by_country(sql_cursor,USA)
['The Doors']
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your connection is setup already, the following should give you the "name" parameter from your table.

```
def band_by_country(sql_cursor,country):
    bands = []
    for row in sql_cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE country=?', (country,)):
        bands.append( row[0] )
    return bands
```

If you want to join table1 with table2 it would look like this:

```
def band_by_country(sql_cursor,country):
    bands = []
    for row in sql_cursor.execute(
        "SELECT table2.artist_name FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON "
        "table1.id=table2.artist_id WHERE table1.country=?", (country,)):
        bands.append( row[0] )
    return bands
```

Comment: I'd make that `SELECT DISTINCT`, otherwise your second query looks good.

Comment: There are some bands with the same name. If there are two rows in the database, then I don't want to remove them from results.